# How to lock form from editing based on condition at Odoo10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

This is what I have tried so far, but it seems that it doesn't work the way it would word on a field. Also I tried making it options="{'edit': [('template_is_locked', '=', False)]}".

```
<form string="Templates" attrs="{'edit': [('template_is_locked', '=', False)]}">

</form>
```

Another thing that I've tried is adding an attribute inside a form and header like this:

```
<attribute name="edit">
     [('template_is_locked', '=', False)]
</attribute>
```

Seems like form element simple don't react to any field changes. Maybe some of you had similar problem and you could share it with me.

Comment: in odoo attrs not affect  on form its only works on field

Comment: Yeah i figured it out. But what would be the solution for this problem? Say  I want to lock form on button click.

Comment: use a readonly attribute on the field(s) concerned`<field name="name" attrs="{'readonly': [('template_is_locked', '=', False)]}" />`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I have so farm. It works, but i had to set this readonly thing for all fields (which might be more then 100 in a single form). That's why I asked if i can lock whole Form.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way to dynamically lock the entire form itself. The only workaround, as @danidee mentioned, is to set the readonly attrs on each field individually.

Normally Odoo core models handle this situation like this:

```
name = fields.Char('Name', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
```

Model with a field, `state`, which other fields can be `readonly` based on the state.

The `name` field is always readonly unless the record is in the Draft state.